# Deserialize json with duplicate keys using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I am trying to parse a json payload **with duplicate** keys to a `Map<String, List<String>>` using Jackson

Consider the following payload

```json
{
"foo" : "val1",
"foo" : "val2",
"bar" : "val3"
}
```

I want to convert this to a `Map<String, List<String>>` type.

ex:

```
+--------------+----------------------+
| Key (String) | Value (List<String>) |
+--------------+----------------------+
| foo          | [val1, val2]         |
| bar          | [val3]               |
+--------------+----------------------+
```

What would be the best way to handle this with Jackson? I'm hoping that there's a way in Jackson where I can register a custom deserialization logic for `Map<String, List<String>>` type. (Note that I have no control over the json payload sent in the request)

Appreciate any help on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if it works for you.

Using `@JsonAnySetter` to deserialize unmapped JSON properties. `@JsonAnySetter` annotation can be used to define "any setter" mutator.

Using `@JsonAnyGetter` Annotation to serialize any arbitrary properties. `@JsonAnyGetter` can be used on a method which returns a Map.

POJO Definition

Test.java

```
package oct2020.json;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;

public class Test {
    
    private Map<String, List<String>> keyValuesMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    /**
     * @return the keyValuesMap
     */
    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, List<String>> getKeyValuesMap() {
        return keyValuesMap;
    }

    /**
     * @param keyValuesMap
     *            the keyValuesMap to set
     */
    public void setKeyValuesMap(Map<String, List<String>> keyValuesMap) {
        this.keyValuesMap = keyValuesMap;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void duplicateKeyValues(String key, String value) {
        List<String> values = null;
        if (!keyValuesMap.containsKey(key)) {
            values = new ArrayList<String>();
        } else {
            values = keyValuesMap.get(key);
        }
        values.add(value);
        keyValuesMap.put(key, values);
    }
}
```

Converting the json to desired format.

JSONConverter .java

```
package oct2020.json;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JSONConverter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = "{\n\"foo\" : \"val1\",\n\"foo\" : \"val2\",\n\"bar\" : \"val3\"\n,"
                + "\n\"bar\" : \"val3\"\n,\n\"bar\" : \"val3\"\n,\n\"bar\" : \"val3\"\n,"
                + "\n\"bar\" : \"val3\"\n,\n\"bar\" : \"val3\"\n,\n\"bar\" : \"val3\"\n,"
                + "\n\"bar\" : \"val3\"\n,\n\"bar\" : \"val3\"\n,\n\"bar\" : \"val3\"}";
        Test test = mapper.readValue(json, Test.class);
        Map<String, List<String>> keyValuesMap = test.getKeyValuesMap();
        System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                .writeValueAsString(keyValuesMap));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "bar" : [ "val3", "val3", "val3", "val3", "val3", "val3", "val3", "val3", "val3", "val3" ],
  "foo" : [ "val1", "val2" ]
}
```

Comment: @Lucifer does this solution answer your question ?

Comment: I tried this abroach with `List<Object>` instead of `List<String>` but still the `MAP` ignores the duplicate fields. It is overriding the previous values and storing the last value from the `JSON`. I tried using the `MultiMap` still no luck. Seems like Jackson itself is not reading the duplicate key and their values or maybe its not sending to `POJO` where I have the field with `@JsonAnySetter` and `@Jsond.AnyGetter` and help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

please put this property JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY in the @JsonTypeInfo annotation. It might work.